# Community Promotion Ads - 2016

Tags: discussion, community-ads

It's 2016 now, and we've [made some changes to the sidebar size](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272563/were-standardizing-the-sidebar-width-at-300px-on-all-sites). As such, we can now restart the Community Promotion Ads for 2016!

Keep in mind, we have updated some of the guidelines compared to previously - the changes are marked in bold in the Image Requirements section.

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- interesting Blender addons, tutorials, and other resources
- relevant events, conferences, or meetups
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **300 x 250 pixels**, or double that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of **150 KB**
- **If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px (2px if high DPI) border surrounding it.**

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/1009).

Answer (score 19):

[image: Blend-Exchange!]

Comment: Support [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), the free long-term .blend hosting site. This ad will show new users where they can upload .blend files, and remind experienced users.

Comment: Like this a lot

Comment: Extra Info: The blend count is dynamic and updates directly from the blend-exchange server.

Comment: That is so cool! It makes me want to upload a blend just to see if the count updates :-)

Comment: still at 859.... I'm waiting for it to go up.....

Comment: @X-27  It's gone up.

Comment: That is sooo Cool   !!!!!!!!!

Comment: I don't *think* I need to ding this for the border because while it isn't solid, it's still around the whole ad so its shape is still very clear. And also the regulations didn't SAY solid though it's a lot easier to do it that way...

Comment: I always wondered how blendheads look like. Awesome!

Comment: It's not a bug, it ...should be... a feature !

Answer (score 14):

[image: All the blender news you can handle!]

Comment: what happened to "no more than 250px width?

Comment: @RadishofKnowledge 2x resolution for retina happened.

Comment: Filesize is too big, must be 150KB or less

Answer (score 12):

[image]

Comment: Support the proposed Stack Exchange site for other 3D programs and 3D theories. You may need this resource in the future as you expand your tool set - many already feel the need now!

Comment: This proposal will also support questions about Lux Render and other opensource 3D tools, so it could very likely become immediately useful to you.

Comment: Could the down voters give some feedback? if there are issues with the ad, they can be fixed.

Comment: I gave a downvote as I don't personally see it as a good advert, design wise or message wise, particularly when comparing it to the bright, clear, blendernation advert, currently above. Are general users of the site aware of what a 'proposed site' is and that it will be on SE? I think the image looks quite drab in terms of colour and not really a 'modern' design. I also find the 'Get the answers you need' to be very generic as it gives no indication as to what answers I will find. No offence meant, all just opinion of course.

Comment: @RayMairlot Trying to explain your message in its entirety is not always possible in a tiny little sidebar ad. I personally prefer giving enough information to make someone click for more. Besides, not all the ads here need to be targeted for general users. This one is more aimed at the top 10%, which is that is needed from this site to make the proposal happen - which is why the add was made in the first place. This add will do its job, and that makes it good enough in my eyes. Of course if someone has a specific suggestion, I'll try it out. I always like to improve my work :).

Comment: Exploreing is spelt Exploring..... and depending where you live modeling may have 2 L's

Comment: @angussidney Ah thanks for that, it makes the layout work better :) (as well as not make more literate people than I cringe)

Comment: Filesize is too big, must be under 150KB

Comment: @GraceNote Fixed

Comment: Some odd messaging here... as if Blender users are in the dark and should be looking elsewhere to be *enlightened*. Also, there was a "3D Graphics" SE site that went into beta and ended up closing - http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5022/3d-graphics, How will this be different?

Comment: @ideasman42 How will this site be different - not very, but that is not a problem 1: There are enough questions, basically ever question on this site, x3 or four, plus more relating to scanning and other fields. 2: There are enough people, Max and Maya users alone eclipse the size of the blender community. Therefore this site *can* make it. The issue is the right people aren't on SE, and this time we will try (once the site is launched), to post and share the site across the internet.

Comment: @ideasman42 In a sense blender users live in a dark box of one software package. Most commercial software users/professionals can name 6 or 7 packages that make up their workflow. I have explored other software a bit recently (specifically for texture painting), and have discovered how much really good tools can help. Blender can render and model well, but it simply cannot compete with commercial offerings in many areas. B.SE users might benefit from a resource if they ever do leave their one software workflow, and that is what this add is advertising.

Comment: PS: Choking this ad is going to send this new 3D modeling proposal the way of the last one.

Comment: That there was a last one is even more confusing ... it was just a few clicks away from the re-proposed 51 site to the message that it was closed 4 years ago. http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5022/3d-graphics ... these two need to be decoupled somehow.

Answer (score 4):

[image: Help this community grow -- follow us on twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted, now with 80px more width! It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting. Gonna need to update the graphic soon though...

Comment: Can we actually have this as one of the circulated ads.

Answer (score 2):

[image: See all questions with active bounties]

Comment: Adapted from [Community Promotion Ads - 2016](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/a/2719) - it will show the number of questions with bounties if these exist. The size is *not* a problem.